# How to set system environment variable from Mapper Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

**The problem below the line is solved but I am facing another problem.**

I am doing this :

```
DistributedCache.createSymlink(job.getConfiguration()); 
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI   
("hdfs:/user/hadoop/harsh/libnative1.so"),conf.getConfiguration());
```

and in the mapper :

```
System.loadLibrary("libnative1.so");
```

(i also tried 
System.loadLibrary("libnative1");
System.loadLibrary("native1");

But I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no libnative1.so in java.library.path
```

I am totally clueless what should I set java.library.path to ..
I tried setting it to /home and copied every .so from distributed cache to /home/ but still it didn't work :(

Any suggestions / solutions please?

<strike>IIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII</strike>

I want to set the system environment variable (specifically, LD_LIBRARY_PATH) of the machine where the mapper is running.

I tried :

```
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr=run.exec("export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH");
```

But it throws IOException.

I also know about

```
JobConf.MAPRED_MAP_TASK_ENV
```

But I am using hadoop version 0.20.2 which has Job & Configuration instead of JobConf.

I am unable to find any such variable, and this is also not a Hadoop specific environment variable but a system environment variable.

Any solution/suggestion?
Thanks in advance..

Comment: this looks a new issue, so raise a new question or else it will loose focus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why dont you export this variable on all nodes of the cluster ?

Anyways, use the [Configuration](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.205.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html) class as below while submitting the Job

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("mapred.map.child.env",<string value>);
Job job = new Job(conf);
```

The format of the value is k1=v1,k2=v2

Comment: I tried this but seems it doesn't work for me. I grepped hadoop source code and didn't find `mapred.map.child.env`. I am using hadoop 0.20.1

Comment: @DeepNightTwo Seems that its been removed in 0.20.1.