# How to set system env of mapper?

Tags: hadoop, environment-variables

First I tried [How to set system environment variable from Mapper Hadoop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246301/how-to-set-system-environment-variable-from-mapper-hadoop) but `mapred.map.child.env` doesn't work for me.

I am using hadoop 0.20.1. I wanna to pass all system env from the class that started the job to mapper. Here is what I do:

```
    StringBuilder envStr = new StringBuilder();
    for (Entry<String, String> entry : System.getenv().entrySet()) {
        envStr.append(entry.getKey() + "=" + entry.getValue() + ",");
    }
    if (envStr.length() > 0) {
        envStr.deleteCharAt(envStr.length() - 1);
    }
    // System.out.println("Setting mapper child env to :" + envStr);
    getConf().set("mapred.map.child.env", envStr.toString());
```

But It doesn't work. I also tried just set one system value but it does't work either. In Mapper the System.getenv doesn't contains the value. But job.xml has the key and value. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What specific piece of information are you trying to pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your hadoop is too old. This is a bug of hadoop 0.20.

Plz updgrade to 0.21 or more stable 1.0.x.

See [related jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-5981) and [hadoop 0.21.0 release note](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.21.0/releasenotes.html)  for more information.